# OpenSSL created Certificate Authority works with Windows 10 but not Ubuntu

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, certificate, ubuntu-18.04, certificate-authority

I create my own Certificate Authority using OpenSSL.
I put the created root certificate on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.
I create a signed certificate which is used in a .NET Core Server (running on Ubuntu).
When accessing the server on Windows 10 using Chrome, the certifiate is valid/secure.
When accessing on Ubuntu, the certificate is invalid.

Here are the steps I took:

Create a CA

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out self-ca.key -passout pass:password 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key self-ca.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out self-ca.pem -passin pass:password
```

Install CA on Ubuntu

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in self-ca.pem -out self-ca.crt
cp self-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/.
update-ca-certificates
```

Install CA on Windows

```
Place certificate under Trusted Root Authorities
```

Create Certificate

req.conf file:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = CA
ST = ON
O = Self Certificate
CN = www.<mysite>.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.<mysite>.com
```

Certificate commands

```
openssl genrsa -out self.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key self.key -config req.conf -out self.csr
openssl x509 -req -in self.csr -CA self-ca.pem -CAkey self-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out self.crt -days 1095 -sha256 -extensions v3_req -extfile req.conf -passin pass:password
```

Create pfx file for use with .NET Core Server:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey self.key -in self.crt -out self.pfx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome in Ubuntu uses [NSS database](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Security_Services) instead of global /etc/ssl storage.

The command `certutil` can be used to import your certificate to the user-level NSS db.

Install certutil: `sudo apt install libnss3-tools`

Add your CA certificate: `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb/ -A -n "My private CA" -i CA_cert.pem  -t "C,C,C"`

This command will install the certificate from file `CA_Cert.pem` under the name `My private CA` as trusted root for SSL cerver certificates, S/MIME certificates and code signing sertificates.

To check that the certificate is installed: `certutil -L -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb/`